Can I use only mutex and condition variable Instead of the Banker's Algorithm?
I've been studying the Banker's Algorithm and was curious if I could implement a similar resource management system using only Mutex and Condvar. The code I wrote is a synchronization program that allows multiple threads to request and use three types of resources (A, B, and C). Each resource has a certain quantity, and the threads request in order and use the resources, then return them. To manage synchronization, it uses Mutex and Condvar.
Key Operation Details

Resource Initialization: Each resource (A, B, C) has an initial quantity (3, 4, 5), and Mutex and Condvar are used to manage them.
Thread Creation: Three threads are created, and each thread requests resources within an infinite loop.
Resource Request and Usage:


Each thread requests resources and waits using Condvar if the required quantity is not available.
The threads acquire the necessary amount of resources and immediately unlock them.
At the end of the loop, threads lock the resources again and increase the quantities.
When returning resources, Condvar is used to notify other waiting threads.

Here's my code:
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::thread;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let resources = Arc::new((
        (Mutex::new(3), Condvar::new()),  // Amount of Resource A
        (Mutex::new(4), Condvar::new()),  // Amount of Resource B
        (Mutex::new(5), Condvar::new()),  // Amount of Resource C
    ));

    let mut handles = vec![];

    for _ in 0..3 {
        let res = Arc::clone(&resources);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

            loop {
                let a_amount = rng.gen_range(0..4);
                let b_amount = rng.gen_range(0..5);
                let c_amount = rng.gen_range(0..6);

                // Request and wait for resource A
                {
                    let mut a = res.0.0.lock().unwrap();
                    while *a < a_amount {
                        a = res.0.1.wait(a).unwrap();
                    }
                    *a -= a_amount;
                } // Drop the lock on resource A

                // Request and wait for resource B
                {
                    let mut b = res.1.0.lock().unwrap();
                    while *b < b_amount {
                        b = res.1.1.wait(b).unwrap();
                    }
                    *b -= b_amount;
                } // Drop the lock on resource B

                // Request and wait for resource C
                {
                    let mut c = res.2.0.lock().unwrap();
                    while *c < c_amount {
                        c = res.2.1.wait(c).unwrap();
                    }
                    *c -= c_amount;
                } // Drop the lock on resource C

                println!("Thread {:?} borrowed A:{}, B:{}, C:{}", thread::current().id(), a_amount, b_amount, c_amount);

                thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(rng.gen_range(100..500)));

                // Return resources and notify waiting threads
                {
                    let mut a = res.0.0.lock().unwrap();
                    *a += a_amount;
                    res.0.1.notify_one();
                }

                {
                    let mut b = res.1.0.lock().unwrap();
                    *b += b_amount;
                    res.1.1.notify_one();
                }

                {
                    let mut c = res.2.0.lock().unwrap();
                    *c += c_amount;
                    res.2.1.notify_one();
                }
            }
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}

Questions:

Can this approach replace the Banker's Algorithm?

While I believe there are no deadlock issues, could there be
starvation or fairness problems? For example:
Resource A has 10 units.
The first thread constantly needs 5 units of Resource A in each loop.
The second thread constantly needs 3 units of Resource A in each loop.
The third thread constantly needs 9 units of Resource A in each loop.
The third thread will forever sleep.

Are there any other potential issues with this implementation?



Your code is apparently deadlock-free, but... it is not a banker's algorithm: there is no banker here. The code works only because all clients acquire resources in the same order. The whole point of the banker's algorithm is that the banker can see the worst case future when the order of request is not guaranteed. Consider process 1 requests resource A, and process 2 requests resource B - how do you know (without a banker) that the second request is safe?

@vnp Thank you for your response. I realized that I misunderstood the banker's algorithm. I posted my question hastily without fully understanding the algorithm.

Ladder or Lattice
The idea of requesting resources in a single defined order is also known as a "Lock Ladder", or if using multiple axes of progressions, a "Lock Lattice".
As you have neatly discovered, it eschews the requirement for a central authority.
Enforcement
Your current implementation lacks enforcement. There's nothing preventing another thread from accidentally requesting the resources in the wrong order, leading to a deadlock.
In order to enforce the ladder, the typical implementation will:

Assign a level to each resource.
Enforce that resources are acquired in strict ascending (or descending) level order on each thread.

Enforcement will require encapsulation of the resource (so it can only be accessed through the enforcement mechanism) and a thread-local variable to keep track of the last level acquired on each thread.
Starvation & Fairness
It will depend on the fairness of the underlying mutex.
Not all mutex implementations are fair, because fairness may require additional book-keeping, overhead, and/or complexity.
If the underlying mutex implementations are not fair, then your algorithm won't either... but that's not really something to do with the algorithm. To fix it, you'd either switch to a fair mutex implementation or implement fairness yourself (via a queue, for example).
Starvation (kinda)
One potential issue, which here goes undetected, is if one thread were to require more than the maximum ever available.
There's only 4 of A, if a thread asks for 5 or more, then it'll always be denied.
An improvement to the API would be the track the maximum available of each resource, and raise an error in case a thread asks for more, rather than letting it loop endlessly or wait forever.
Also, you may simply decide that no thread should ever hog more than 50% (or whatever) of each resource instead of using the hard maximum.
Starvation (definitely)
Manual unlocking and notifying is so error prone. If any thread aborts prematurely (error, panic), then it will never release it resources, and the other threads may starve forever.
Acquisition & Release of resources should thus be encapsulated to ensure that even on early return or unwinding, the resources are released.
Termination
One issue regularly faced with applications in general, and multi-threaded applications in particular, is how to achieve an orderly and responsive termination.
In your case, the termination should be orderly, but... responsiveness could likely be improved. If we imagine the worst-case, at the moment the application is asked to terminate:

A is hogging sufficient resources that no other thread can run, and is just getting started on its task.
A finishes, releasing its resources.
B seizes the resources, preventing C to complete its task.
B finishes, releasing its resources.
C seizes the resources, and completes its task.

Thus, from the termination order to actual termination, you may have 3 tasks worth of time, plus some minor overhead.
It would be useful to define interruption points in the algorithm: points at which the algorithm can be interrupted safely -- whatever that means for the application.
In general, a good place for an interruption point is after a potentially long operation, as statistically speaking the task is more likely to be interrupted during its longest segment than during its shortest... and waiting for the shortest to be completed doesn't take long, by definition.
